# Controlling execution of event handlers sequence

Tags: c#, outlook, imanage

We are trying to develop an addin for outlook. Our client is already using another addin provided by another vendor. We are trying to customize the outlook send event (`ItemSend` event). Unfortunately our handler has to execute after the other vendor's event handler is executed.

Can we control the execution sequence of event handlers?

Thanks,
Naresh

Comment: You've to subscribe event handler after `another vendor` has subscribed to it. that's it.

Comment: how we will get to know that the other vendor is subscribed to event or not?

Comment: Take a look at my answer